# How to get pandas to groupby print when dictionary has different sized columns per key

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I use a list that looks like this:

```
partlist = [ 'PART1', 'PART2','PART3', 'PART4', 'PART5', 'PART6' ]
```

Then parse through a few thousand files looking for devices with those parts.  I could end up with a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'hostname1': ['MODEL', 'PART1'], 'hostname2': ['MODEL', 'PART1']}
```

or:

```
{'hostname1': ['MODEL', 'PART1', 'PART2', 'PART1', 'PART1', 'PART1', 'PART4' ], 'hostname2': ['MODEL', 'PART1', PART1', 'PART4']}
```

My for loop ends with:

```
(path,file) = os.path.split(device)
create_dictionary()
```

Allowing me to create my dictionary using the filename as the key which matches the hostname of the device (easiest way to keep the key unique i could think of, and allow additional features in the script down the road)

```
def create_dictionary():
    key = file
    mydict.setdefault(key, [])
    mydict[key].append(model)
    mydict[key].append(part)
    return mydict
```

Then I have a call to print using pandas

```
def print_sorted():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict,'index')
    df.columns=['model', 'part']
    print(df.groupby(['model','part']).size())
```

But with this pandas call If a device has more than the model and just 'one' of the 146 parts in my partslist, this pandas call quits and gives up with the length error about the axis because my dictionary has more than 2 values per key.

Does anyone know how to make it so that the it will allow any number of values in the columns/groupby with the knowledge that the first value will always be the model of the device, and anything after is going to be a part?

Thanks in advance for your help.   This one has had me stumped looking through SO, and random python/pandas sites for weeks.

Comment: What do you mean by "If a device has more than the model and just 'one' of the 146 parts.." can you include an example of the type of input that would generate the error? There's almost enough information here to try to reproduce the issue locally, which help you get an answer back...

Comment: What would you want the output of your script to look like? Can you add to your question an example dataframe of what it would look like to have "the first value always be the model of the device, and anything after is going to be a part"?